# How to log from Javascript Module in Firefox extension

Tags: firefox-addon, javascript

I'm modifying a Firefox extension that has been written by someone else, and I'm not very experienced with Javascript and Firefox, so my question is probably fairly simple.

I have a lot of code in a Javascript Module (.jsm file), and I want to produce some outputs form this module to help with debugging. I can't seem to use javascript alerts (`alert("blah");`) or log to the javascript console (`console.log("blah");`) as both of these give errors saying that `console` or `alert` cannot be found.

Is there any way to produce this sort of debugging output from code running in a Javascript Module? All I want is simple text output to help with my development/debugging process.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182816/how-do-you-log-to-firebug-from-an-extension

Comment: Thanks for the link, unfortunately none of those answers work for me. I always get an error saying that `window` or `Firebug` is undefined. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two common options:

- Use [dump()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.dump), the output will be printed to OS console (on Windows you need to run Firefox with `-console` command line option to see it).
- Use [Component.utils.reportError](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Components.utils.reportError), the output will be printed to Error Console - use Ctrl-Shift-J to open it.