# Logging to console from Firefox extension?

Tags: firefox, logging, firefox-addon, firebug, firefox-addon-sdk

I understand that I can log to the console when using a Firefox extension with the `cfx run` command.

Is there a way to log to a console after the extension has been packaged with `cfx xpi`? Logging to Firebug is fine if possible.

I have found two blog posts about this ([here](http://www.timrosenblatt.com/blog/2008/07/23/firefox-extension-debugging/) and [here](http://markhansen.co.nz/firefox-extension-console/)). Both are rather old and don't work any more.

I'm using version 1.10 of the add-on SDK and FF15.

Answer (score 34):

You need to do 2 things:

1. [enable logging for addons](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2013/03/27/changes-to-console-log-behaviour-in-sdk-1-14/)

• in about:config, add a new option `extensions.sdk.console.logLevel` and give it the value "all"

• restart Firefox

2. in Firefox open the [Browser Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console):

• Tools -> Web developer -> Browser console

• NOTE: this is different from the usual Web Console used to debug web pages

You should see addons logs there now.

Comment: Shortcut for browser console is Ctrl+Shift+J

Comment: In addition, you need to enable the option "Show Content Messages" from within the Browser Console.

Comment: I'm using Firefox 91 and those 2 things are still true and needed, but I would add that the option `extensions.sdk.console.logLevel` was not pre-existing in my config as I was assuming, which slightly confused me.

Comment: This needed an update - I posted an update in this thread.

Answer (score 7):

TLDR:

1. Go to `about:config` url and **create key** `extensions.sdk.console.logLevel` with value `all`
2. See log messages either in *Browser console* (Ctrl+Shift+J) or in terminal you started Firefox from.

---

`cfx` or its successor `jpm` creates this configuration key automatically in development firefox profile.

From [logging documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/console#Setting_the_Logging_Level):

> `extensions.sdk.console.logLevel`: if set, this determines the logging level for all installed SDK-based add-ons.
>
> `extensions.extensionID.sdk.console.logLevel`, where extensionID is an add-on's Program ID. If set, this determines the logging level for
> the specified add-on. This overrides the global preference if both
> preferences are set.

Comment: As mentioned by @ojchase under another answer, you also need to enable "Show Content Messages" in the Browser Console settings.

Answer (score 2):

I will summarize recent changes that has taken with Firefox since this question got posted -- basically updated @LucaBonavita answer.

1. In about:config, check if option `extensions.sdk.console.logLevel` is **enabled**. If not, toggle to enable. You might need to create it if it does not exist
2. Open [Browser Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console)

- Menu Bar -> Tools -> Browser Tools -> Browser Console
- Enable `Show Content Messages` in browser console.

[image]

Now, `console.log` triggered by Firefox addon/extension should display

> Tested on Firefox 94.0.2 (64-bit) and 95.0b12 (64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `console.log()` with Firebug? (I know you have tried `Application.console.log()` and `Firebug.console.log()` already)

I just tried it in the Web Console on FF16 running Firebug 1.10.4 and it seems to work: [image: Firefox Web Console]

Here are some more examples from the Firebug Wiki itself: [FirebugWiki Console API](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API#console.log.28object.5B.2C_object.2C_....5D.29)

Additionally, you can write messages of different types in the console, such as: `console.debug()`, `console.info()`, `console.warn()`, `console.error()`

Comment: You're not doing this from an add-on though right? I can `console.log()` from the console itself (or from a web page) no problem. The issue is accessing the console from within the context of an add-on.

Comment: @DavidTuite: Sorry, I missed that part. Have you tried the suggestions in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182816/how-do-you-log-to-firebug-from-an-extension) already?

Comment: That seems to just suggest using the `Firebug` object like one of the blog posts I linked to did. I don't seem to be able to access that even though I have Firebug installed.

Comment: @DavidTuite: That's expected - Firebug is absolutely useless for extensions, it's meant for web pages only.

Comment: I tried `console.log` but it didn't seem to work, but `Application.console.log` worked.

Answer (score -1):

If you run console.log from Add-on code, it send up in the 'Messages' tab of the Error Console window:

[image: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s1/sh/c40c509d-9f14-4103-920b-4186a426226c/53572f96a3bbe0462103a8126b8e9822/res/fcbead60-d9d0-48be-b744-3fa6701fdf1b/skitch.png]

Comment: Warning - this answer is extremely old and no longer relevant. The second answer is the one you want.