# Firefox extension js error log, where?

Tags: javascript, firefox, logging, firefox-addon

I just started getting into Mozilla Firefox extensions, and I'm sure I'll do a lot of mistakes, but I am unable to find errors nor logs from my extension's javascript.

My main.js:

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
var self = require("sdk/self");

pageMod.PageMod({
    include: "https://www.google.ee/*",
    contentScriptFile: self.data.url("popup.js")
});
```

where in popup.js I tried Application.console.log("message"); Firebug.Console.log("message"); console.log("message"); Components.utils.reportError(e); randomly deleted some semicolons and tried calling for object properties that do not exist (document.body.asdasdasd="asd"; etc.)
[popup.js also inserted message into page body, so I can confirm the code was executed]

I have checked Ctrl+Shift+k; Ctrl+Shift+j; Firebug's console, all of them are empty or show errors from webpage only. In my about:config extensions.logging.enabled=true and javascript.options.showInConsole=true.

What could I be missing or where do extension javascript logs appear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you don't have your logging level turned off:

```
extensions.sdk.console.logLevel
```

[Logging Levels](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/console.html#Logging%20Levels)

Comment: Thanks, this was what i was missing, didn't even have extensions.sdk.console.logLevel, added it manually

Answer (score 4):

There are a few ways this can be set

1. define [JPM preferences](http://work.erikvold.com/jetpack-pro-tip/2014/09/30/jpm-prefs.html)

create `firefox-prefs.json` with your defined preferences.

```
{
  "extensions.sdk.console.logLevel": "all"
}
```

then include it with your command line call

```
jpm --prefs=./firefox-prefs.json test
```

2. Define the preference in your code

using the [preferences service](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/preferences_service) include the following at the top of your `index.js`, `lib/main.js` or `test/helper.js`

```
require("sdk/preferences/service").set('extensions.sdk.console.logLevel', 'all');
```

3. Manually configure the preference in your browser `about:config`.

   1. visit `about:config`
   2. right click > New > String
   3. enter preference name 'extensions.sdk.console.logLevel' with value 'all'

[image]

Source:

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable addons logging and make sure you read logs on the [Browser Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console) instead of the Web Console (see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24104946/582995)).